# iOS:Convert string data to 2 byte array and send to CRC

Tags: ios, objective-c, integer, hex, arrays

i am doing application based on conversion of the string data to byte array and My problem is i need to convert the string data and send it to crc algorithm in response to that it give some value here the code  what i did.

```
Byte comm[12];
comm[0]=0x01;
comm[1]=0x14;
comm[2]=0x26;
comm[3]=0x00;
comm[4]=0x01;
comm[5]=0x01;
comm[6]=0x01;
comm[7]=0x01;
comm[8]=0x01;
comm[9]=0x01;
comm[10]=0x01;
comm[11]=0x01;
```

instead of 0x01 from comm[4] to comm[11] i need to place the data  from the string i.e

```
 NSString *stringsdata=@"2015010202113030";
```

i need to convert the string data to byte format as per following

```
 year: 2 bytes
 month: 1 byte
 date of month: 1 byte
 day of week: 1 byte
 hour: 1 byte
 minute: 1 byte
 second: 1 byte
```

i have give the whole data in the above string and that string i need to convert  to bytes and place in the above comm[4] to comm[11] please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you're trying to do since you have a 16 byte string and trying to put into an 8 byte space.
seems like you're trying to split the string up and store each 2 characters as an integer?
I'm not too sure if this is the best way to go about it but it seems to do what you need :)
I don't really deal with data at this level so any critique about what I did would be welcomed!

```
Byte comm[12];
comm[0]=0x01;
comm[1]=0x14;
comm[2]=0x26;
comm[3]=0x00;
comm[4]=0x01;
comm[5]=0x01;
comm[6]=0x01;
comm[7]=0x01;
comm[8]=0x01;
comm[9]=0x01;
comm[10]=0x01;
comm[11]=0x01;

NSString *stringsdata=@"2015010202113030";

NSInteger length = stringsdata.length;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 2){

    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(i, 2);
    NSString *chunk = [stringsdata substringWithRange:range];

    comm[(i/2) + 4] = [chunk intValue];

}

NSLog(@"%d", comm[4]);
NSLog(@"%d", comm[5]);
NSLog(@"%d", comm[6]);
...
...
NSLog(@"%d", comm[11]);
```

Comment: can u let me know is it integer value i the comm[] and if its integer need to convert it to byte data please let me know